# Algorithm to determine a single line passing through squares in a grid

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Basically, I have a grid with certain contiguous cells marked (in grey) as below:[image: Line Through Grid]

I want to draw a line intersecting all the squares. It has be a single line and it must necessarily be intersecting with all the marked squares, but it can intersect non-marked cells too. Is there any algorithm/sample program for determining such a line? I am not knowledgeable about geometric algorithms in general, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you could use *Bresenham's line drawing* algorithm then check that the 'pixels' the line passes through are the same as the ones in your set.

Comment: Must the line we are looking for be straight?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a line segment. Sorry if it was not clear from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line ax + b doesn’t intersect a square if either it is above the square both at the left and the right side of the square or below the square at both sides of the square. This gives you a formula to calculate possible values of b depending on a. In your case with the square at 0, 0 to 1, 1 you need to avoid b where b<0 and a+b <0, or b>1 and a+b > 1. Then you add restrictions for the second square and so on. There may not be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A conceivable way is Line fitting with an objective function that returns very bad values if some grid does not intersect the line(: Penalty Method) .

I think this is not the best, but may become one way.